# ambiguous reference to overloaded definition when call method in java library

Tags: java, scala, reference, ambiguous

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON

object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val map = new util.HashMap[CharSequence, CharSequence]()
    map.put("123", "22333")
    map.put("test", null)
    val ret = JSON.toJSONString(map)
    println(ret)
   }
}
```

the `toJSONString` functiones :

```
public static String toJSONString(Object object) {
    return toJSONString(object, emptyFilters, new SerializerFeature[0]);
}

public static String toJSONString(Object object, SerializerFeature... features) {
    return toJSONString(object, DEFAULT_GENERATE_FEATURE, features);
}
```

the error:

```
Error:ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,both method toJSONString in object JSON of
type (x$1: Any, x$2: com.alibaba.fastjson.serializer.SerializerFeature*)String
and method toJSONString in object JSON of
type (x$1: Any)String 
match argument types (java.util.HashMap[CharSequence,CharSequence])
val ret = JSON.toJSONString(map)
```

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8344 where `f(a,b,c)` can be taken as `f(Tuple3(a,b,c))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Scala overloading logic does not match Java logic. You have to call it like this:

```
JSON.toJSONString(map, SerializerFeature.PrettyFormat)
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

with applause!

args `SerializerFeature.EMPTY: _*` as default format!

```scala
val jsonString = JSON.toJSONString(obj, SerializerFeature.EMPTY: _*)
```

refs: https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson/issues/1282#issuecomment-624461007